# Passing lots of variables between threads for logging purposes efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, memory, dynamic, allocation

I am using VS 2005

I have about 10-12 variables of different types such as double, int, string, long and bool that I want to log on another thread with min. overhead.

Currently, each time when I have to log, I "new" an arraylist, add all variables in it and then pass it as an argument to LoggerClass.Log(). In LoggerClass it sets/resets the event and another thread reads the value of arraylist.

Since the function gets called a lot, doing "new" is not very efficient and I am looking for a way to pass all the values to another thread without dynamic memory allocation.

One alternate in my mind is to not "new" the arraylist but just keep adding to it but the problem with that is the size of arraylist can become enoromous.

Any suggestions?

Heres the code

```
//This function gets called a thousand times per second

private void MyLogic(MyClass LogObj)
{

  ArrayList MyArrList = new ArrayList(15);//This line causes periodic performance outliers
                            MyArrList.Add("Q");
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.valString);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValDouble);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValInt);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.valString2);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValDouble2);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValInt2);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.valString3);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValDouble3);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValInt3);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.valString4);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValDouble4);
                            MyArrList.Add(LogObj.ValInt4);

  MyLogger.Log(MyArrList);
}


Class MyLogger
{
  private Queue         m_logQueue;

  public void Log(ArrayList LogArr) 
  {
    lock (m_LogQueue)
    {
      m_LogQueue.Enqueue(LogArr);
    }

    m_Event.Set();
  }
}

private void LogThread()
{           
  ArrayList ValuesToLog = new ArrayList(); 
  StringBuilder StringBuf = new StringBuilder(); 
  string csFileName = "MyLog";

  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(csFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
  {
    while (m_bRun)
    {
      m_Event.WaitOne();
      try 
      {
        while (true)
        {
          lock (m_logQueue)
          {
            if (m_logQueue.Count > 0)
            {
              ValuesToLog = (ArrayList)m_logQueue.Dequeue();                                     
            }
            else
              break;
          }

          StringBuf = new StringBuilder();
          StringBuf.Append(DateTime.Now);
          StringBuf.Append(",");

          for (int i = 0; i < (ValuesToLog.Count - 1); i++)
          {
            StringBuf.Append(",");
            StringBuf.Append(ValuesToLog[i]);
          }

          sw.WriteLine(StringBuf.ToString());

          if (m_bAbort) break;
          if (m_EventStop.WaitOne(0, true))
            break;
        }
        sw.Flush();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `List<T>`?  ArrayLists are so .Net 1.1.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: He's passing different types.

Comment: I think we need more information before we can provide a helpful answer. First, what is the reason you are trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation? Is it (a) because you don't want to see each of your simple types (double, int, long, etc) boxed individually? Or is it just because you perceive dynamic memory allocation to be slow?  Second, how does your logger work? Does it take some number of records which are intended to be logged and then write them to storage? Could this number of records be variable or is it fixed?

Comment: I perceive dynamic memory allocation to be slow and more importantly, it causes periodic performance outliers and it also keeps garbage collector busy.

Comment: "I perceive dynamic memory allocation to be slow" -- have you actually measured whether it's a problem?  The GC is blisteringly fast at allocating, and it's also geared towards sweeping up short-lived objects.  Unless you're spamming zillions of log messages every second, I doubt it'll be a problem.  To avoid Array reallocation, you could also ensure that the List<object> is initialised with the correct number of elements prior to filling it up.

Comment: Yes, I actually measured it with and without the "new" and it does make a difference. Also, it does log a lot, a few thousand times per second. I have added code sample in the original post for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really sure that the problem is allocating new list every time, you can recycle them.

Have a collection of unused lists, that starts empty. When there is a list in the collection, take that (and remove it from the collection). Otherwise, create a new one. When you finish logging, `Clear()` the list and return it to the collection.

Of course, you access the collection from multiple threads, so you have make sure you're accessing it in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Say I instantiate 1000 ARrayList at the startup and add them in a Queue. MyLogic() can get an arraylist from the collection and use that . MyLogger.LogThread() can then log the values from arraylist and call a clear() on it? My question is, how does MyLogic() know which arrayList to get? I thought the index will be an autoincrement number and once it reaches 1000, it starts getting arraylist from the queue at index 1.

Comment: The one `Dequeue()` returns. And you don't have to worry about how the `Queue` (or better, `Queue<T>`) manages its indexes, it will do it correctly. But you have to count with the case that there is no unused list in the collection.

Comment: I see.. So you mean at the startup I enqueue 1000 arraylists. Then MyLogic() calls MyQueue.Dequeue function to get an arraylist and add values to it and pass that arraylist to the loggerthread. Loggerthread can then clear() the arraylist it got from MyLogic(). Just wondering, when I Say Queue.Dequeue, will Queue re-use the arraylist that was previously used and then cleared afterwards? or will the Queue dynamically just keep increasing its size without reusing the previously cleared arraylists?

Comment: If that was all you did, you would soon run out of lists. `Clear()` just removes the data from the list. But you have to add the list back to the collection to reuse it. To do that, you have to `Enqueue()` the list to the collection. If you do this, the queue reuses the old lists, but it doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: What is the best collection to use to store the arraylists? I tried Queue but it is not typed and you have to cast it. SEcond option is List<T> but I dont know if it is fast with queue and dequeue. I will be causing queue and dequeue a lot, probably thousand times, if not more in a second.

Comment: The obvious choice is `Queue<T>`. It behaves the same as `Queue`, except that it's generic (typed). Both enqueue and dequeue are O(1).

Comment: I wonder if there is a way not to lock the Queue<t> while enqueuing and dequeueing. In C++ there is a way to lock only the portion of memory (a specific index of queue in this case) which is being enQd or deQd while leaving the remaining queue unlocked.

Comment: You can do that, but correctly implementing something like that is quite difficult. You should do something like that only if you're absolutely sure the locking is what's slowing down your code. Or you could use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` from .Net 4, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any measurements and I don't necessarily agree with your conclusions or your approach to this type of logging, but I'm not going to let that stop me from making a suggestion...

```
//Use this to hold the information that you want to log.
public class LogRecord
{
  private IEnumerable<object> values;

  public LogRecord(params object [] data)
  {
    LogTime = DateTime.Now;
    values = data;
  }

  public DateTime LogTime { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<object> Values 
  { 
    get
    {
      yield return LogTime;
      foreach(var v in values) yield return v;
    }
  }
}

//
private void MyLogic(MyClass LogObj)
{
  var record = new LogRecord("Q", LogObj.Var1, LogObj.Var2, LogObj.Var3);
  MyLogger.Log(record);
}

class MyLogger
{
  public void Log(LogRecord record)
  {
    //Do a bunch of threading stuff...

    string msg = string.Join(",", record.Values);

    //Write the message to the stream
  }
}
```

There is still a `new` in there, but this approach (creating a new logging record for each logging statement) is used by other popular logging frameworks like log4net, NLog, and EnterpriseLibrary.  As far as I know, you don't hear many complaints about performance in those frameworks.

I don't know if this is any better or worse than what you have.  Also, I don't know if it addresses the performance problem that you said that you have seen.  On the other hand, it does simplify the code quite a bit, both for creating the logging message and for combining it into a string for writing to the stream.

If you are extremenly concerned with peformance and if your information is logged a thousand times per second, you might look at NLog's CurrentTimeGetter implementation.  Its purpose is to optimize time retrieval, given that the time often does not change from one logged message to the next.  You can find it at this link:

https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Internal/CurrentTimeGetter.cs

My ultimate recommendation would probably be to try to use an existing logging framework like log4net or NLog.  These days I personally would recommend giving NLog a try first as it has just had a major new release.

Comment: I had another new in my code which I was able to remove and majority of the performance outliers were gone.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.ToString() may be a problem. Perhaps consider using something else? This gave me quite a boost in performance --

```
char[] buffer = new char[21];

static string DateTimeNowToString()     
{

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    buffer[2] = buffer[5] = '.';         
    buffer[8] = ' ';         
    buffer[11] = buffer[14] = buffer[17] = ':';         
    Write2(buffer, now.Month, 0);         
    Write2(buffer, now.Day, 3);         
    Write2(buffer, now.Year % 100, 6);         
    Write2(buffer, now.Hour, 9);         
    Write2(buffer, now.Minute, 12);         
    Write2(buffer, now.Second, 15);         
    Write3(buffer, now.Millisecond, 18);

    return new String(buffer)
}     

static void Write2(char[] buffer, int value, int offset)     
{         
    buffer[offset++] = (char)('0' + (value / 10));         
    buffer[offset] = (char)('0' + (value % 10));     
}

static void Write3(char[] buffer, int value, int offset)     
{        
    buffer[offset++] = (char)('0' + (value / 100));         
    buffer[offset++] = (char)('0' + ((value / 10) % 10));         
    buffer[offset] = (char)('0' + (value % 10));     
}
```

Comment: Thats true, DateTime.Now is bad, but I do it on loggerthread, so that should'nt effect my normal processing.